# Michael Hartl Tut 3 Ch 9 - UserLoginTest Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am struggling with an error I am getting around the start of chapter 9. When I am running my test, I encounter the following fail state:

```
..F

Failure:
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout [C:/webf5201/alcottgriffinj/lab4/test/integration/users_login_test.rb:27]:
Expected exactly 0 elements matching "a[href="/login"]", found 1..
Expected: 0
  Actual: 1
```

I have seen the other questions posted on stack regarding this. However, the solutions offered were already present in my code. I started encountering the error once we began to make the changes to the user.rb file in Chapter 9. However, I cannot see what is causing the error myself..

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def User.digest(string)
    cost = ActiveModel::SecurePassword.min_cost ? BCrypt::Engine::MIN_COST :
                                                  BCrypt::Engine.cost
    BCrypt::Password.create(string, cost: cost)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def User.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end
end
```

**user_login_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    def setup
        @user = users(:michael)
    end 

    test "login with invalid informatiion" do
        get login_path
        assert_template 'sessions/new'
        post login_path, params: {session: {email: "", password: ""}}
        assert_template 'sessions/new'
        assert_not flash.empty?
        get root_path
        assert flash.empty?
    end

    test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
        get login_path
        post login_path, params: { session: { email:    @user.email,
                                              password: 'password' } }
        assert is_logged_in?
        assert_redirected_to @user
        follow_redirect!
        assert_template 'users/show'
        assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
        assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
        delete logout_path
        assert_not is_logged_in?
        assert_redirected_to root_url
        follow_redirect!
        assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,         count: 0
        assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user),    count: 0
     end
end
```

**_header.html.erb**

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container">
    <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
        <% if logged_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
              Account <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Log out", logout_path, method: "delete" %>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Log in", login_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: pretty sure the hartl tutorial has a git repo with commits corresponding to the code changes. So if you're copying the code verbatim you could clone that repo and revert to the appropriate commit. Otherwise, if you want to debug your code, look at what the error is telling you - it sees the "log in" button and doesn't expect to. Possibly your `if logged_in?` check is evaluating it to false. It's kind of difficult to say why this check is failing, but this would be a fine opportunity to install & learn to use a debugger such as `byebug`.

Comment: This ends up on the users/show page. Can you verify that your show page does not have a login link